# Prove $\alpha: \mathbb{Z_n} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z_n}$ defined by $\alpha(s)=rs\mod{n}$ is an automorphism.

Tags: abstract-algebra, modular-arithmetic

I'm working on proving the following claim:

"Let $r \in U(n)$ and $\forall s \in \mathbb{Z_n}$, $\alpha: \mathbb{Z_n} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z_n}$ defined by $\alpha(s)=rs\mod{n}$ is an automorphism."

I've already proven *one-to-one* and *onto*, but can't quite figure out how to show that the mapping preserves operations (it intuitively seems obvious, I think).  Anyway, here's what I've got:

$\alpha(a+b)=[r(a+b)]\mod{n}=(ra+rb)\mod{n}=(ra\mod{n}+rb\mod{n})\mod{n}=(\alpha(a) + \alpha (b))\mod{n}.$

But, $ (\alpha(a) + \alpha (b))\mod{n}$ doesn't necessarily equal $\alpha(a)+\alpha(b)$.  Consider $\alpha(a)=n-1$ and $\alpha(b)=1$, then $\alpha(a) + \alpha (b)=n \not \in \mathbb{Z_n}$ .

Am I going about this wrong?  How do I correctly show that $\alpha$ preserves the operation?

Comment: why $n\notin \mathbb{Z}_n$? ($n=0$ mod $n$)

Comment: You're completely right.  I don't know why I overlooked that... Thank you.

Comment: I'm new to stack exchange.  How do I mark as answered?  Or, should I just take down the post?

Answer (score 0):

But, The question is to show that the map $\alpha$ is well defined, i.e if $s=s' $ mod $n$ then $rs=rs'$ mod $n$.

Comment: Isn't that obvious though?  If $s'\equiv s$ $(\mod{n})$, then $rs'\equiv rs$ $(\mod{n})$.  What does that have to do with proving $\alpha: \mathbb{Z_n} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z_n}$ is isomorphic for $\alpha(s) = rs \mod{n}$?

Comment: proving is defined